# Package install failed, Angular on Vagrant

Tags: angular, vagrant, angular-cli

This is what I have done, I created vagrant machine, this is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
end
```

and mine bootstrap.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

I just vagrant up, and I could see http://127.0.0.1:4567/ without problems.

Then I proceed with https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

```
vagrant ssh
```

It says

> Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

then (after sudo apt-get install curl) as instructed on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

No errors to this point.

Then I proceed with (after sudo apt-get install npm)

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I get this error

> Error: failed to fetch from registry: angular-cli

Not sure what to do, just wanted to try Angular. Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to post your package.json contents in order for someone to be able to help. It looks like one of the packages NPM is trying to install has an invalid package.json of its own, so narrowing down what you're trying to install will help.

Comment: try to check Angular Cli properly installed   ng --version

Comment: just tried to repeat process so I can write a more detailed question and could not pass install of angular-cli

Comment: tried to update npm install npm@latest -g same error, 'Error: failed to fetch from registry: npm'

Answer (score 0):

First set NPM config propriety

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and try install Cli globally level

```
sudo npm uninstall -f -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: when I try to 'npm uninstall -g @angular/cli' I get 'npm WARN Not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules @angular/cli', I tried to clean cache and install it again but again same error

Comment: I still get 'npm WARN Not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules @angular/cli' after sudo npm uninstall -f -g @angular/cli and then 'npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: angular/cli' after last line, thanks for your reply and sorry for my late reply!